# Import private key from pem file into keystore

Tags: java, keystore

I am new in using keystores, is there a way to create a keystore when I have cert file and a private key in pem format? Please help

```
   keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

   keyStore.load(null, pwd.toCharArray());

   String privKeyPEM= privateKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n","");
   privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----","");
   byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM);
   PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
   KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

It fails here `kf.generatePrivate(keySpec)`.
and I got:

```
algid parse error, not a sequence.
```

the rest of the code:

```
   KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(privKey, new Certificate[ {certificate});
   keyStore.setEntry(keyStoreAlias,entry , new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pwd.toCharArray()));
```

Comment: Do you what to create a keystore on runtime, or is it a rather static setup?

Comment: it will be kind of Virtual keystore. I don not know if I import cert correctly too.

Comment: May be this is because I am using pkcs12 and the private key is defined as pkcs8? but I don not know how to do it programmatically

Comment: Please show us where `certificate` comes from.

Comment: can't you import it from the command line just like keytool -import -file yourcert.pem.x509 -keystore MyLocalKeystore -storepass ***** ?

Comment: No, it should be in a code

Comment: Could you try this without the \r\n in the replacements and just \n for the first replacement

Comment: #mikea->then my encoded  variable is null

Comment: @lostInRequests I meant String privKeyPEM= privateKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n",""); and privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",""); sorry

Comment: @mikea - yes, I did it, and the result is null. The problem is that the header and the footer were not replaced.

Comment: this is a long shot, but the last time I needed encryption on runtime with no ks, I used the bouncy castle encrypt library.

Comment: Is it possible to create jks keystore and then somehow convert it to pkcs12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, after some research I ended up with this piece of code, which is perfectly working for me. So, I post it in here, in case if someone is looking for the same solution.

```
        KeyStore keystore;

        java.security.Security.addProvider(
                new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()
        );

        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(privateKey));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();
        PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(pwd.toCharArray());
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair kp;
        if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
            kp = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(decProv));
        } else {
            kp = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
        }
        RSAPrivateKey result = (RSAPrivateKey)kp.getPrivate();

        keystore= KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        keystore.load(null, pwd.toCharArray());
        keystore.setKeyEntry(keyStoreAlias, result, pwd.toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{certificate});
```

Thanks to all who suggested any solutions or put questions.